# Match newlines in non empty lines and not preceded by some characters

Tags: regex, replace, newline

I tried to use the regexp `(?<=^(?![ \t]*@).+)(?<![\{\};:)]|//.{0,1024}|^[ \t]+)\R` to:

- Match newlines without matching preceding characters
- Don't match newlines in only-space lines (empty lines)
- Don't match newlines in lines started by optional spaces (not newlines) and at-symbol '@'.
- Don't match newlines in lines containing [unescaped] '//'.
- Don't match newlines preceded by '{', '}', ';' or ':'. (better if doesn't match newlines preceded by optional spaces and that characters.)

That regexp worked in Eclipse search, but I cannot replace the match because an Eclipse find-and-replace bug. Then I tried it in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and in [TextPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextPad), but they told me that the regexp is malformed. I tried to validate the regexp in a online regexp validator and said me the regex has errors.

How do I construct a correct regexp that satisfy those listed requirements?

```
has to match the new line.
    has to match the new line.
has to match the new line
doesn't have to match the new line;
    doesn't have match the new line     {
doesn't have to match the new line}
doesn't have to match the new line:
doesn't have to match the new line //because of this
@doesn't have to match the new line
h@s to match the new line-
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this regex `^[^@]+[ ]*.*[ ]*([^;{}:]+)[ ]*$`

It will cover you all cases except below one

> doesn't have to match the new line //because of this

Comment: This regexp doesn't match newlines characters '\R'. I tried it and it matches a big amount of lines every match.

Comment: Ohh I considered individual lines. I have verified this new expression `^[ ]*[^@)]{1}[^;{}://\n]+$` in Notepad++. You can give a try to this expression.

Comment: @OliverTarrago If you accept the new answer, I will update the original answer.

Comment: That regex matches the entire line that meet the requirements. I only want to match the newline character of that lines, not the entire line.